# How can I center a flexbox element and make it grow to fill unequal remaining space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Take a look at this Codepen: https://codepen.io/devinhalladay/pen/eyKBpY

[image: Screenshot]
(The image above is a screenshot of the Codepen. The center line indicates where the center of the page is)

**I need to make it so that the `H3` is centered within the page despite unequal widths of the other elements, and the lines on the left and right must fill all the available space on either side.**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Title</a>
  <h3>Subtitle</h3>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 4em;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

h3:before,
h3:after {
  background-color: #ddd;
  content: '\a0';
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
}

// Non-essential styles
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```